# Accessibility - unable to select button behind the modal view by Tap

Tags: ios, button, tap

I am facing one issue where if voice over is on , I am not able to select button1 by Tap only when modal view is present. If VO is off then button1 tap works fine.  I have this sample code.  If I set detents only medium then tap will work fine. Is this some kind of bug or is there any workaround to make tap work.

```
@IBAction func presentModalView(_ sender: UIButton) {        
    let modalViewController = ModalViewController(nibName: "ModalViewController", bundle: nil)
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    if let sheet = modalViewController.sheetPresentationController {
        sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .large
        sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
        sheet.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
    }
    
    self.navigationController?.present(modalViewController, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func button1Tapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("ButtonTapped....")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use in GitHub repo which name is Floating Panel

Check: https://github.com/scenee/FloatingPanel

Answer (score 0):

You want to have Button1 tappable when sheet controller has medium detent. Try setting largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier to medium instead of large:

`sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium`